# Можно ли изменить стилем принудительно установленный цвет в TextBlock

Tags: wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли изменить стилем принудительно установленный цвет в TextBlock
Есть такой код:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="listView">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="С Заданным цветом">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Display}" Foreground="Black"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Каким образом можно изменить его, не убирая параметр Foreground="Black" ?

Comment: Из code-behind.

Зачем Вам это?

Comment: Да решаю задачу... :)
А можно какой нибудь пример?